# Creating class name generator in java

Tags: java, constructor, encapsulation, naming

I am having quite a bit of problems naming variable automatically in java.

**The problem in question :**

I am making a class Point (different from `java.awt.Point`). It has an attribute `this.name`. From a `testPoint.java` I just create a `Point` and print its name.

To create a Point I have two linked constructor :

```
public Point() {
        this("AutoName");
    }

public Point(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

If a name is given in the `testPoint.java`, the point will be named according to that name. If no name is given the Point will be named `AutoName`.

What i want is that if no name is given the first no named Point gets `AutoName1` as a name, the second `AutoName2` etc.

Is there a way to do that without introducing new classes ? It would be easy if I can create a global variable in java like in C and Python but I think that does not respect the encapsulation principle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `static int` in the class to hold the number of instanciation

```java
class Point {
    static int creationCount = 1;
    String name;

    public Point() {
        this("AutoName" + (creationCount++));
    }

    public Point(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point{name='" + name + "'}";
    }
}
```

```
System.out.println(new Point());       // Point{name='AutoName1'}
System.out.println(new Point("abc"));  // Point{name='abc'}
System.out.println(new Point());       // Point{name='AutoName2'}
System.out.println(new Point("bcd"));  // Point{name='bcd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322345/13279831) is fine for a single-thread application, e.g. when there is a single loop creating the points.

However, in case there are several threads creating the instances of `Point` class, the values of `creationCount` may repeat for different points, and defining the counter variable as `static volatile` does not guarantee the uniqieness of its values because pre- and post-increments are not atomic operations.

So, in general case it may be better to use more thread-safe `AtomicInteger` for the mentioned purpose:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Point {
    static AtomicInteger creationCount = new AtomicInteger(1);
    String name;

    public Point() {
        this("AutoName" + creationCount.getAndIncrement());
    }

    public Point(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point{name='" + name + "'}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Was going to point this out myself but you beat me to it. Global mutable state is already bad to make it not-thredsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable to do that:

```
class Point {
  static int counter = 1;
  String name;
  
  public Point() {
    this("AutoName" + counter);
    counter++;
  }

  public Point(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```